# What is the use case for Oracle DB_UNIQUE_NAME and Global Database names

Tags: database, oracle

Oracle database documentation defines the  global database name as below:

> The Oracle Database software identifies a database by its global database name. A global database name consists of the database name and database domain. Usually, the database domain is the same as the network domain, but it need not be. The global database name uniquely distinguishes a database from any other database in the same network. You specify the global database name when you create a database during the installation or using the Oracle Database Configuration Assistant.
>   [Oracle Database Installation Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ntdbi/identifying-databases.html#GUID-EA0D5E1B-06B4-4570-AD9C-2D2B695CE6DC)

Question: How does Oracle enforce unique global database name? For example, say I have a server named ServerA in  my network with an Oracle database called DatabaseA, and I try to install another database with same name on ServerB, will the installation error out ?
How does Oracle find out about the other database ?
I am sure there is some design goal and some use cases for these confusing names. Looking for a proper explanation with sample scenarios.